# bcrypt compareSync returns false even they have same string

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, authentication, bcrypt

I am trying to make login functionality
While I was creating the login function like this

```
login: (req,res) => {
const body = req.body;
getUserByEmail(body.email,(err,results)=>{
  if(err){
    console.log(err); 
  }
  if(!results){
    return res.json({
      sucess: 0,
      data: "Invalid email or password 1"
    });
  }
  console.log(body.pw);
  console.log(results.pw);
  const result = compareSync(body.pw,results.pw);
  console.log(result)
  if(result){
    results.pw = undefined;
    const jsontoken = sign({result: results},"1234413",{
      expiresIn: "1h"
    });
    return res.json({
      sucess: 1,
      message: "login sucessfully",
      token: jsontoken
    });
  }else{
    return res.json({
      sucess: 0,
      data: "Invalid email or password2"
    });
  }
});
}
```

[Terminal Answer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTEu7.png)

I console log the body.pw and results.pw but seems like it give me same strings but
I was not sure why it gives me false result even if I have same string for body.pw and results.pw

Comment: You should first understand what is bcrypt used for. You should not store plain text password in db and use bcrypt just for comparing. You should store the hash produced by bcrypt in the db and compare it when login using the supplied password.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

compareSync compares a password with a hash. You first need to hash the password before comparing it with the plain-text password.

First run

```js
bcrypt.hash(myPlaintextPassword, saltRounds).then(function(hash) {
    // Store hash in your password DB.
});
```

Then you can compare

```js
bcrypt.compare(myPlaintextPassword, hash).then(function(result) {
    // result == true
});
```