# Error: Invalid email/password combination with Node.js and MongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, blockchain

Am trying to login my admin , i defined the login credentials both in the mongodb and in the .env so here is the code which has a problem.

```
const Admin = require('../models/admin');
const Voters = require('../models/voters');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');

exports.checkCredentials = async (req, res, next) => {
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;

  Admin.findOne({ email: email }).exec(async (error, adminData) => {
    if (error) {
      // some error occured
      return res.status(400).json({ error });
    }
    if (adminData) {
      // email is correct checking for password
      const match = await bcrypt.compare(password, adminData.password);
      if (match) {
        req.adminID = adminData._id;
        next();
      } else {
        return res.status(200).json({
          msg: 'Invalid email/password combination yyy',
        });
      }
    } else {
      // no data found for given email
      return res.status(200).json({
        msg: 'Invalid email/password combination !!!!',
      });
    }
  });
};

exports.verifyVoter = async (req, res, next) => {
  let query;
  if (req.query.voterID) {
    query = {
      voterID: req.query.voterID,
    };
  } else {
    query = {
      phone: req.body.phone,
    };
  }
  console.log(query);
  Voters.findOne(query).exec(async (error, voterData) => {
    if (error) {
      // some error occured
      return res.status(400).json({ error });
    }
    if (voterData) {
      // Voter found
      if (voterData.hasRegistered === true) {
        return res.status(200).json({
          msg: 'Voter already registered',
        });
      } else {
        req.phone = voterData.phone;
        req.district = voterData.pinCode;
        req._id = voterData._id;
        next();
      }
    } else {
      // no data found for given Voter
      return res.status(200).json({
        msg: 'Invalid VoterID',
      });
    }
  });
};
```

that code above brings an error but this is how i defined my admin credentials in the .env

```
ADMIN_EMAIL = bkroland19@gmail.com
ADMIN_PASSWORD =felinho/013
```

and  this is how i defined them in mongodb

```
{
    "email": "bkroland19@gmail.com",
    "password": "felinho/013"
}
```

and this is the resulting error i get yet the email am entering matches those two emails.
Any help please

Am expecting to be allowed to login in when i enter the credentials as they are in the mongodb database

Comment: Do you save the password in clear text in mongodb? If yes, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71651541/bcrypt-comparesync-returns-false-even-they-have-same-string


`compare()` of `bcrypt` expects to compare the password in clear text with a hash, not two identical strings.

Comment: could you adjust the code above and show where to clean .thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you store the password in cleartext you don't need `bcrypt.compare`:

```
const match = password === adminData.password;
if (match) {
  req.adminID = adminData._id;
  next();
}
```

Anyway, it is **strongly** suggested to encrypt it, you can do it with:

```
const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(12);
const encryptedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

const user = await Admin.create({ email, password: encryptedPassword });
```